# how to display google map on android emulator?

Tags: android, google-maps

i am new to android development.please tell me how to generate key for google map keys from key store.I tried but i am getting the following error on the emulator.sorry the application hello google maps has stopped unexpectly

my  codes are:: (HelloGoogleMaps.java)

```
package com.java4u.android;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class HelloGoogleMaps extends MapActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      
    }
}
```

Hello Google map manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.java4u.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

<activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps" android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
     <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
       <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="Your Maps API Key goes here"
    />
```

Map Activity.java

```
package com.java4u.android;
import android.app.Activity;
public class MapActivity extends Activity {
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {      
        return false;
    }   
}
```

MapView.java

```
package com.java4u.android;
public class MapView {
    public void setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean b) {
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);    
    }
    private MapView findViewById(int mapview) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: "sorry the application hello google maps has stopped unexpectly" is not a good error description. Please take a look in your LogCat view (in eclipse) or run the command `adb logcat` in console...

Answer (score 0):

As you already said, you need a Google Maps API key to use the MapView. Check [this page](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html) for further information on how to get a key.

After getting the key, pass it to the `android:apiKey` attribute of the MapView in main.xml.

```
android:apiKey="Your Maps API Key goes here"
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you have to add **Api key** in a **main.xml**

try this link get google **Api key** and display google map

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: hello sir thanks for the help but i have problem that when i type C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android and press enter a command prompt screen appears for two seconds and disapperas again.please tell me way so that this could become stable and i could extract  the MD5 fingerprint.